# How to assign a tooltip to a div without javascript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to design a form where I have tool tips that are **ALWAYS** showing on the right side to help the users in filling out their forms. What I did was I assigned each parts in Divs and I want a tool tip for each one.

```
<div title="This is where you fill your first name in.">
            <p> First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"/> </p> 
            </div>
<div title="Last Name Entry">
            <p> Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName"/> </p> 
            </div>
 <div title="OK!">
            <input type="submit" style="width: 10em; margin: auto 0"/>
            </div>
```

I found this neat website that helps you style in CSS with ease and I used a code that I generated through it:

```
a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  width:140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
a.tooltips span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-right: 8px solid #000000;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.8;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

courtesy of:

> http://html-generator.weebly.com/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: on which event the tooltip should be shown ? when you hover the field? On focus?

Comment: Well I would just like it to be always showing if that is possible. Otherwise just focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can give you answer for you question from title.
I always use CSS3 pseudo elements and data atribute to accomplished that without any jQuery code.

This is CSS3:

```
    [data-tip] {
     position:relative
    }
    [data-tip]:before {
        content: '';
        display: none;
        border: 5px solid #000;
        border-top-color: #000;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
        border-left-color: transparent;
        position: absolute;
        top: -7px;
        left: 10px;
        z-index: 8;
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
    [data-tip]:after {
        display: none;
        content: attr(data-tip);
        position: absolute;
        top: -35px;
        left: 0px;
        padding: 0px 8px;
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 9;
        font-size: 13px;
        height: 28px;
        line-height: 28px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        word-wrap: normal;
    }
    [data-tip]:hover:before, [data-tip]:hover:after {
        display: block;
    }
    .tip-below[data-tip]:after {
        top: 23px;
        left: 0px;
    }
    .tip-below[data-tip]:before {
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-bottom-color: #1a1a1a;
        border-left-color: transparent;
        top: 13px;
        left: 10px;
    }
```

And HTML would b:

```
<a href="#" data-tip="Tooltip text here"> some text here </a>
```

Instead of bellow you can make to right side.

Comment: Can I use this for an entire div element? Thank you for the input btw!

Comment: You welcome, I hope it will help you. And sure you will sure need to modify css to suite your needs. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/p3Twq/)**</kbd>

In the fiddle tooltip works on focus but if you remove opacity it'll be always shown

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name"><span class="tooltip">Tooltip 1 content</span>
<input type="text" name="lastName"  placeholder="Last Name"><span class="tooltip">Tooltip 2 content</span>

input {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #555;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;

  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;

  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.tooltip:after, .tooltip:before {
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.tooltip:after {
  border-color: rgba(200,200,200,0);
  border-right-color: #ddd;
  border-width: 8px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
input:focus + .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
}
```